# Read XMl using Linq returning empty object

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read a xml

Sample XML

```
<customer-list>
   <customer>
      <FirstName>B</FirstName>
      <LastName>C</LastName>
      <Email></Email>
      <OptInEmail>1</OptInEmail>
      <Phone>9056953000</Phone>
      <Address1></Address1>
      <Address2>70 East Beaver Creek Rd</Address2>
      <City>Richmond Hill</City>
      <State>ON</State>
      <ZipCode>L4B3B2</ZipCode>
      <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode>
   </customer>
   <customer>
    <FirstName>P</FirstName>
    <LastName>M</LastName>
    <Email></Email>
    <OptInEmail>1</OptInEmail>
    <Phone>7045955246</Phone>
    <Address1>Residence Inn</Address1>
    <Address2>55 Minthorn Blvd</Address2>
    <City>Markham</City>
    <State>ON</State>
    <ZipCode>L3T7Y9</ZipCode>
    <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode>
   </customer>  
</customer-list>
```

Reading Code

```
public void ReadXml(string path)
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var customer = from node in xdoc.Descendants("customer")
                            select new
                            {
                                FirstName = (string)node.Attribute("FirstName").Value,
                                LastName = (string)node.Attribute("LastName").Value,
                                Email = (string)node.Attribute("Email").Value,
                                OptInEmail = (string)node.Attribute("OptInEmail").Value,
                                Phone = (string)node.Attribute("Phone").Value,
                                Address1 = (string)node.Attribute("Address1").Value,
                                Address2 = (string)node.Attribute("Address2").Value,
                                City = (string)node.Attribute("City").Value,
                                State = (string)node.Attribute("State").Value,
                                ZipCode = (string)node.Attribute("ZipCode").Value,
                                CountryCode = (string)node.Attribute("CountryCode").Value
                            };

            foreach (var item in customer)
            {
                var test = item.FirstName;
            }
        }
```

but every time i try to access it , Cutomer is  empty. No values read from xml?? Any suggestion...

**Updated code based on leo suggestion.**

```
 public void ReadXml(string path)
    {
        var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var customer = from node in xdoc.Descendants("customer")
                        select new
                        {
                            FirstName = node.Element("FirstName"),
                            LastName = node.Element("LastName"),
                            Email = node.Element("Email"),
                            OptInEmail = node.Element("OptInEmail"),
                            Phone = node.Element("Phone"),
                            Address1 = node.Element("Address1"),
                            Address2 = node.Element("Address2"),
                            City = node.Element("City"),
                            State = node.Element("State"),
                            ZipCode = node.Element("ZipCode"),
                            CountryCode = node.Element("CountryCode")
                        };

        foreach (var item in customer)
        {
            var test = item.FirstName;
        }
    }
```

**not working.**

**Updated code as per salem22 suggetions. No business rule or logic return.After reading just going over foreach loop to run it, not working.**

```
public void ReadXml(string path)
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
            var customer = from node in xdoc.Descendants("customer")
                            select new
                            {
                                FirstName = node.Element("FirstName").Value,
                                LastName = node.Element("LastName").Value,
                                Email = node.Element("Email").Value,
                                OptInEmail = node.Element("OptInEmail").Value,
                                Phone = node.Element("Phone").Value,
                                Address1 = node.Element("Address1").Value,
                                Address2 = node.Element("Address2").Value,
                                City = node.Element("City").Value,
                                State = node.Element("State").Value,
                                ZipCode = node.Element("ZipCode").Value,
                                CountryCode = node.Element("CountryCode").Value
                            };

            foreach (var item in customer)
            {
                var test = item.FirstName;
            }
        }
```

**Adding the actual file that i am seeing after reading in `xdoc`**

```
<customers xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2007-05-31">
 <customer-list>
 <customer>
  <FirstName>B</FirstName> 
  <LastName>C</LastName> 
  <Email></Email> 
  <OptInEmail>1</OptInEmail> 
  <Phone>9056953000</Phone> 
  <Address1>On</Address1> 
  <Address2>70 East Beaver Creek Rd</Address2> 
  <City>Richmond Hill</City> 
  <State>ON</State> 
  <ZipCode>L4B3B2</ZipCode> 
  <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode> 
  </customer>
 <customer>
  <FirstName>P</FirstName> 
  <LastName>M</LastName> 
  <Email></Email> 
  <OptInEmail>1</OptInEmail> 
  <Phone>7045955246</Phone> 
  <Address1>Residence Inn</Address1> 
  <Address2>55 Minthorn Blvd</Address2> 
  <City>Markham</City> 
  <State>ON</State> 
  <ZipCode>L3T7Y9</ZipCode> 
  <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode> 
  </customer>


  </customer-list>
  </customers>
```

Comment: down voters put comment to understand what is wrong with the question...

Comment: Lol, why do you keep silence about namespace in your XML? :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  XDocument xd=Xdocument.Load(path);
  XNamespace ns = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2007-05-31";

  var customer=from node in xd.Descendants(ns+"customer")
               select new
               {
                 FirstName=node.Element(ns+"FirstName").Value,
                 ...
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `Elements` not `Attributes`. Use `XElement.Element(string)` method

```
FirstName = (string)node.Element("FirstName"),
LastName = (string)node.Element("LastName"),
...
```

Also don't use the `Value` property if you are making explicit cast. it's pointless. `Value` is already a string, and it will throw an exception if the element wasn't found.

Comment: it is not giving any value

Comment: hmm it seems another bug in LINQ to XML. it works for everyone but not for you. let me report it to .NET team

Comment: Thanks for your sarcasm i have listed the full code here. You tell me @Selmaan22 
            foreach (var item in customer)
            {
                var test = item.FirstName;
            } not giving inside the loop.Have you actualy run the code in a solution and tried to run it .

Comment: you should be doing something else wrong. that code will throw exception when you use .Attribute before foreach... you said customer is empty which is not possible.

Comment: i have posted the updated code not working.... and try to run it in vs console to see for yourself......

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the call to `Attribute` with `Element` because your `customer` don't have any attributes and you are interested in getting the inner elements' text. Replace all method calls similar to the one below...

```
FirstName = (string)node.Attribute("FirstName").Value,
```

with this...

```
FirstName = node.Element("FirstName").Value,
```

Comment: @ankur are you sure? Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: foreach (var item in customer)
            {
                var test = item.FirstName;
            }  it is not going inside the loop. also when i take customer to quick watch and do customer.Tolist() , it is giving0 as count

Comment: @ankur Show me how your try this

Comment: @ankur can you inspect what exactly you are passing in the `path` variable? And then open that xml file "manually" using any other text editor such as notepad

Answer (score -1):

You get nothing because there aren't any attributes to read.The element "customer" is a complexType element that has children elements (firstname,lastname, etc.) . In order to read their values you have to change the method from node.Attribute to node.Element . 
With the XML you posted i runned the following code and got the desired results.

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var customer = from node in xdoc.Descendants("customer")

select new
{
    FirstName = node.Element("FirstName").Value.ToString(),
    LastName = node.Element("LastName").Value.ToString(),
    Email = node.Element("Email").Value.ToString(),

    foreach (var item in customer)
    {
        var test = item.FirstName;
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
```